# Ionic2 Typescript Generically Push Type as Page to NavCtrl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, ionic2

I'm making a generic CRUD service using Ionic2 with typescript.

I have this class but i've omitted all of the data that is not pertinent to the problem:

```
export class UsersPage {

  users: User[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
                                                    private usersProvider: Users) {
      super(navCtrl, navParams, usersProvider);
  }

  navigateToDetail(userId: number) {
      this.navCtrl.push(ProfilePage, {userId})
  }
}
```

I converted it to this generic class but visual studio is generating an error that I'm attemting to use a type as a value

```
export class PageListBase<T extends IHasId, TDetailPage extends PageBase<T>> {
     navigateToDetail(id: number) {
         this.navCtrl.push(TDetailPage, {id})
     }

}
```

I'm receiving an error:

> TDetailPage only refers to a type but is being used as a value here

How can I pass the Type as the value to the nave controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by passing the type as an instance to the base but I'd like some clarification on what an import actually is.

```
export class PageListBase<T extends IHasId> {

    public entityList: T[];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public baseProvider: ProviderBase<T>, public instance: any) {

        baseProvider.getList().subscribe(entities => {
            this.entityList = entities;
            console.log(entities);
        });
    }

    navigateToDetail(id: number) {
        this.navCtrl.push(this.instance, { id })
    }
}
```